# How to Omit an interface from an interface

Tags: typescript, interface

I would want to know if it is possible to omit several keys at once without having to specify them all in case they are already known from a specific interface.

Let's imagine I have the following interfaces :

```
interface A {
  a: number;
  b: number;
  c: number;
  d: number;
}

interface B extends A {
  e: string;
  f: string;
}
```

I would want to have a type referring to the following object :

```
const a: SomeType = {
  e: 'foo',
  f: 'bar',
};
```

I could do something like this but it would be very redundant :

```
type OmitWithKeys = Omit<B, 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'd'>
```

And it would be the same problem for this solution if B has many keys :

```
type BWithoutExtend = {
  e: string;
  f: string;
};
```

Is there any trick to achieve this ?

Comment: Are you just looking to "subtract" the keys of `A` from the keys of `B`? Or are you looking to get some subset of `B`'s keys?

Comment: @VLAZ I want to "substract" the keys of A from the keys of B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
type BWithoutExtend = Omit<B, keyof A>;
```

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted,  thank you.